# Dock Widget on other Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

I want to "dock" the Text Widget you can see on the Picture on the GridView. My approach looks like this:

[image: docked]

```
Container(
            height: 500,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.count(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    crossAxisCount: 7,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.6,
                    children: List.generate(dates.length, (index) {
                      final date = firstMonth.add(Duration(days: index));
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          //print(DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: date.day == DateTime.now().day && date.month == DateTime.now().month && date.year == DateTime.now().year ? Colors.red : Colors.grey[700]!),
                          ),
                          child: dates[index],
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("Information"),
                Text("more Information"),

              ],
            ),
          )
```

The problem it's when we look at February it's not docked, its floating in the void now:
[image]

Either I cut the Calendar or it's floating in the no man's land. Is there a way to dock it to the GridView?
I already tried to use just an expanded but then the GridView takes way too much space, more than it actually needs, so the Text Widget is at the bottom...
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try using stack widget it is created for "dock" some widget over the other

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The Stack with docked seems to work also but I found another solution without adding a Stack:

```
      Column(
        children: [
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 7,
            childAspectRatio: 0.6,
            children: List.generate(dates.length, (index) {
              final date = firstMonth.add(Duration(days: index));
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  //print(DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day));
                },
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: date.day == DateTime.now().day && date.month == DateTime.now().month && date.year == DateTime.now().year
                            ? Colors.red
                            : Colors.grey[700]!),
                  ),
                  child: dates[index],
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Text("more Information"),
              Text("more Information"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Here it's also docked